# Android Studio for Mac: Use original colour image for splash screen

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen, android-image

I have a multi-color image that I wish to use on a splash screen. I am using a guide [from here](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565) which requires specifying the image under a `AppTheme.Launcher` `style`, and using the `item` `android:windowBackground` to specify the image name through `@Drawable/SplashIcon`

I am stuck on how to actually add the image to the project. I have so far been adding images using the menu action `new -> Image Asset` which flattens the colour and doesn't seem to have an option to just import as is.

I have resorted to drag and drop onto the `drawable` folder in Android Studio, which adds the image, but I cannot reference it using `Drawable/SplashIcon`.

Here is what I have:

[image]

[image]

How do I reference my image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it is an issue with the file name. Have to use lowercase letters and underscores for the file name, nothing else.

I therefore drag and dropped my image with the name `splash_icon.png` and it's now appearing under `@drawable/...`

I am also now using the different pixel densities too, as recommended.